# Is it possible to add methods to JQuery's promise object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a `catch` method to JQuery's `promise` object so I don't have to type the following every time:

```
.then(null,function(data){
    // handle error
    return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
});
```

Also, it'll make it easier to read. How would I do this in JQuery 1.11?

Comment: Why not just add a proper promise library which offers a `catch` method and use that instead?

Comment: Btw, `$.Deferred().resolve().promise()` --- you don't need the last `.promise()` call here

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible, but I would strongly recommend not to do this. Rather use a proper promise library and assimilate your jQuery promises; so that you can use the libraries builtin (and correct) `.catch()` method - so that you can omit that `return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();` line as well.

The problem with extending jQuery promises is that they don't inherit from a prototype which we could simply amend, but use a factory pattern (read [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.11-stable/src/deferred.js#L9)). You'll need to [decorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) it:

```
jQuery.Deferred = (function($Deferred) {
    var Deferred = function(func) {
        var deferred = $Deferred(func),
            promise = deferred.promise();
        deferred.catch = promise.catch = function(fnFail) {
            return promise.then(null, fnFail);
        };
        return deferred;
    };
    return Deferred;
}(jQuery.Deferred));
```

Comment: I'm intruiged by your phrase 'proper promise library'. Would you categorise the native html5 promises as 'proper'? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: @AndrewShepherd: Proper as in https://promisesaplus.com/. Yes, the native ES6 promises are acceptable (though have very few features)

Comment: @Bergi What is purpose of `Deferred.when = $Deferred.when;` ?

Comment: @guest271314: Well spotted. I somehow imagined that [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) would be `$.Deferred.when` - and all static properties on the overwritten function need to be copied to make the decorated one work.

Comment: @Bergi See lines 292, 293, 297 at https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a644101ed04d0beacea864ce805e0c4f86ba1cd1/src/deferred.js ? Should this be a canonical Question / Answer ? Has the Question _"Is it possible to add methods to JQuery's promise object?"_ been previously asked at SO ?

Comment: @guest271314: 1) Yes, I see them, is there anything special about them? 2) Sure, treat it as a canonical if you want. 3) You can easily find that out by using the search

Comment: @Bergi 1) Appear that at 293 `$.when` calls previously created `deferred.promise` , else calls `$.Deferred()` , which would include `.delay` , or other methods set within IIFE defining `$.Deferred` ? 2) Yes, ok. 3) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Is+it+possible+to+add+methods+to+JQuery%27s+promise+object%3F

Comment: @guest271314: Yes, `$.when` would use the overwritten `$.Deferred`, and all objects created from that would have the custom methods.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I wouldn't use jQuery "Promises" at all since they do not even follow the spec. Use the bluebird library, for example.

Answer (score -1):

You can create your custom **then**

```
$.Deferred().prototype.customthen = function(){
  $.Deferred().prototype.then.call(this, null, ,function(data){
    // handle error
    return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
  })
}
```

You have added a new function named **customthen** to the prototype. So, this new function is available in all instances.

Now, you can use it as follows

```
.customthen();
```

Comment: What is `<Object>`? Do you really mean to extend the native `Object` prototype?

Comment: Which object has the function **then** ? Your answer will be the <Object>

Comment: It's stated in the question. And no, jQuery deferreds don't use a `.prototype`.

Comment: this is the object you are looking for https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: So please fill in the code in your answer, to make it fit to the question.

Comment: Edited ... i hope this cover your expectations :)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this doesn't work, as `$.Deferred()` instances do not have a `.prototype`.