# How do I create a jQuery plugin extending $.Deferred?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-deferred

I want to extend `$.Deferred` with a new method which is supposed to have a signature similar to [`Deferred.fail()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/). What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: since Deffered is an object and not a widget you could extend it wiht $,Deffered.prototype.newFunc = function(){}

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15743/custom-function-extending-jquery-deferred

Comment: @Dan Kuida your suggestion doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/alexarg/9c1f5rmj/

Comment: first of all in the fiddle you sent, the $.Deferred is not defined. Second what you really want si to extend what $.Deferred() returns and not $.Deferred itself. There is an option to pass a parameter and to extend it on one execution var def = $.Deferred(function(){this.test = function(){alert("test")}}); so in order to override the constructor of that function you need to insert the above method inside it.

Comment: I disagree, $.Deferred is defined in the jsfiddle. But you're right that I need to extend the object that Deferred function returns rather then extending the function itself. Your suggestion with passing a function will only work for the deferred object that was created with the function parameter, while I want to enable the function for all deferred objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way to do it.

I'm overriding $.Deferred with a new function that calls the base function and extends the object it returns with a new method:

```
$._Deferred = $.Deferred;
$.Deferred = function (param) {
    var deferredToExtend = $._Deferred(param);

    deferredToExtend.test = function (param) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        deferredToExtend.always(deferred.resolve.bind(deferred, param));
        return deferred.promise();
    };

    return deferredToExtend;
};
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexarg/9c1f5rmj/)

Comment: `.test` appear to return `undefined` if chained to `.then` ? see http://jsfiddle.net/9c1f5rmj/10/ ; see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719454/is-it-possible-to-add-methods-to-jquerys-promise-object , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746979/delay-for-jquery-promises